# raspbian (rasp pi 3) connection to database (mysql / mariadb)

Tags: c++, mysql, raspberry-pi, mariadb, debian-based

I am stucked. 
I am relative neewbie in Linux with some previous exp. in php programming.

I want write a script with my raspi pi 3, qt, and databases. 
I am unable to get database connection work.

all tutorials are counting either with cppconn, libmysqlclient(-dev), mysql.h. 
Non of that I am able to get on to my Raspi.

I have MariaDB installed and configured, I also installed mysql, and mysql-common. 
And that where I stucked. 
Unable to build the script in C++, because mysql.h is missing.

Can you please help me out of this situation?

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you get CppConn onto your RasPi?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-installation-source.html has instructions for building from source, which should be all you need

Comment: You are correct. I was able to download and install on raspi cppconn. I was also able to setup and get to running simple "hello world" skript. What bothers me is that I am not able to write skript on Netbeans Windows, a than run it on Rasppi. On windows I have problem with boost .

Comment: in detail: inside of mysql_connection.h is include declaration of #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp> with err "there are unresolved includes inside". Do you know please what I can do about that too? Thank you

Comment: That is a separate question. Ask it as such.   (Preferably with a lot more detail, and a minimal example)

Comment: thank you Martin. Regarding issue of building and compiling script on windows, while the same version of the script was compiled succesfully on Linux is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125796/build-c-script-with-err-mysqlcppconn-missing-no-such-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Martin Bonner said - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-installation-source.html this was solution for my problem. I installed this package on Linux with apt-get install lmysqlcppconn.
I also make sure that all source are in /usr/include/