# build c++ script with err mysqlcppconn missing (no such file)

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, netbeans

there is a newbie to c++.

I want to prepare working environment for C++ development for Raspi 3. 
This includes C++ (netbeans IDE on windows, geany on Raspi), mysql (mariDB) and QT.

first step was a simple script "hello world" on raspi and make a build with help of cppconn. 
Second step was make the same script on windows in Netbeans IDE, and build it localy/remotely.

I have this simple script:

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: marek
 *
 * Created on 1. listopadu 2017, 22:33
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
  Include directly the different
  headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
  (and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/
#include <mysql_connection.h>
#include <mysql_driver.h>

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>



using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

cout << endl;
cout << "running select as a messege" << endl;

try {
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://10.0.0.6:3306", "root", "FTQERJSC");

  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("mysql");

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column data by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
  }
  delete res;
  delete stmt;
  delete con;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
  cout << "̣# ERR: SQLException in "    << __FILE__; 
  cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl; 
  cout << "̣# ERR: " << e.what(); 
  cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << ")" << endl; 
}

cout << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;




std::cout << "hello world pc 5 mysql\n"; 

#ifdef __linux__ 
    std::cout << "__linux__\n";  
#elif defined(__unix__)
    std::cout << "__unix__\n";  
#elif defined(_WIN64)
    std::cout << "_WIN64\n";  
#elif defined(_WIN32)
    std::cout << "_WIN32\n";  
#endif


#if __WORDSIZE == 64 
    std::cout << "64 bit\n";
#else 
    std::cout << "32 bit\n";  
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

During build I get these Errors:

```
cd 'C:\Users\marek\Documents\c++ projects\hello-world-7-pc-mysql'
C:\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/marek/Documents/c++ projects/hello-world-7-pc-mysql'
"/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW_Qt-Windows/hello-world-7-pc-mysql.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/marek/Documents/c++ projects/hello-world-7-pc-mysql'
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW_Qt-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW_Qt-Windows/hello-world-7-pc-mysql build/Debug/MinGW_Qt-Windows/main.o -L/C/Program\ Files/MySQL/MySQL\ Connector\ C++\ 1.1.9/lib -L/C/Program\ Files/MySQL/MySQL\ Connector\ C++\ 1.1.9/include/cppconn -L/C/Program\ Files/MySQL/MySQL\ Connector\ C++\ 1.1.9/include -lmysqlcppconn-static -lmysqlcppconn "/C/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.9/lib/opt/mysqlcppconn-static.lib" "/C/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.9/lib/opt/mysqlcppconn.lib" -lmysqlcppconn  
c:/Qt/Qt5.9.2/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmysqlcppconn-static
c:/Qt/Qt5.9.2/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmysqlcppconn
c:/Qt/Qt5.9.2/Tools/mingw530_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmysqlcppconn
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW_Qt-Windows/hello-world-7-pc-mysql.exe] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/marek/Documents/c++ projects/hello-world-7-pc-mysql'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/marek/Documents/c++ projects/hello-world-7-pc-mysql'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 858ms)
```

Totaly frustrated with setting up Mysql for C++ coding.

Please advice :)

Thank you,
Marek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reformatted your command line and your error message for better readability (specifically I put in line breaks, and normalized the path to `ld`).

> ```
> g++ -o dist/Debug/MinGW_Qt-Windows/hello-world-7-pc-mysql \ 
>    build/Debug/MinGW_Qt-Windows/main.o \
>   -L/C/Program\ Files/MySQL/MySQL\ Connector\ C++\ 1.1.9/lib \
>   -L/C/Program\ Files/MySQL/MySQL\ Connector\ C++\ 1.1.9/include/cppconn \
>   -L/C/Program\ Files/MySQL/MySQL\ Connector C++\ 1.1.9/include \
>   -lmysqlcppconn-static \
>   -lmysqlcppconn \
>   "/C/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.9/lib/opt/mysqlcppconn-static.lib" \
>   "/C/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.9/lib/opt/mysqlcppconn.lib" \
>   -lmysqlcppconn
> c:/Qt/Qt5.9.2/Tools/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmysqlcppconn-static
> c:/Qt/Qt5.9.2/Tools/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmysqlcppconn
> c:/Qt/Qt5.9.2/Tools/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmysqlcppconn
> ```

The first thing to say is that `ld` is failing to find files call `-lmysqlconn`.  That is very strange, because normally, `-l` means "load the library called `libmysqlconn` with type `.a` or `.so`".  However there are a number of very strange things about your command line:

Firstly `-L` is the command line option to specify where to find *libraries* (.lib, .so, .a, .dll) - so why are you specifing `include` directories?

Secondly, why are you specifying both `-lmysqlconn-static` *and* `-lmysqlconn`?  You either want a static library, or a dynamic library - not both.

Thirdly, why are you trying to explicitly specify the library names (in the `/C/...` lines).

Fourthly, why do you specify `-lmysqlcppconn` twice?

I think you need to change the command line to be something like:

```
g++ -o dist/Debug/MinGW_Qt-Windows/hello-world-7-pc-mysql \ 
  -L/C/Program\ Files/MySQL/MySQL\ Connector\ C++\ 1.1.9/lib \
  -lmysqlcppconn \
  build/Debug/MinGW_Qt-Windows/main.o
```

Finally, I think you need to read through the Qt tutorial carefully.  At the moment, you seem to be just flailing around.

Comment: Based on you comment I was able to clean up settings of NetBeans. Now my build is terminated with these errors:
g++    -c -g -I/C/Program\ Files/boost/boost_1_65_1 -include /C/Program\ Files/MySQL/MySQL\ Connector\ C++\ 1.1.9/include/mysql_connection.h -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
In file included from <command-line>:31:0:
c:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.9/include/mysql_connection.h:30:32: fatal error: cppconn/connection.h: No such file or directory
 #include <cppconn/connection.h>

Comment: my question is why. In path c:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.9/include/ is folder "cppconn" and I copied "boost" folder too. There is some problem with recursion includes or something like that :/ setting up this environment is hell. really.

Comment: in next step I cleaned Include headers, and Include directories in compiler settings including these directories: "C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_65_1";"C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.9/include"
with g++ command: 
g++    -c -g -I/C/Program\ Files/boost/boost_1_65_1 -I/C/Program\ Files/MySQL/MySQL\ Connector\ C++\ 1.1.9/include -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp

Comment: I am totally lost. If I use MiniGW than i get bunch of typeof declaration error, build terminated. If i use miniGW QT than build is completed. Than during run I get this message:
The application failed with exit code -1073741515 (0xc0000135). 
This could indicate that no required .dll was found in the PATH. 
Please try to start the following command from the command shell (cmd.exe). 
This may give some additional information. 

"C:\Users\marek\Documents\c++ projects\hello-world-7-pc-mysql\dist\Debug\MinGW_Qt-Windows\hello-world-7-pc-mysql.exe"

Comment: I was able to take one more step. I tried to run executable file from windows CMD. The error said, that mysqlcppconn.dll is missing. I added up mysqlcppconn.dll in the same folder with my executable and I was able to run program. Now I get error:
RUN FAILED (exit value 255, total time: 3s)